# Gremlin - Stop creating multiple edges

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

My scenario is to pick random participants say 2 who are participated in the competition. And create an edge (for updating their score, i.e, 200 for winners and 100 for participants) to the competition.

For winners, it is working fine. But, for the remaining vertices(i.e participants) wonGift edge is creating multiple times from participant to competition.

In the case of generating 2 winners out of 12 participants, winners should get 200 points and the remaining participants should get 100 points. And also for each winner and participant, new game vertex should be added with the property gameID(which should be generated randomly). And also **I am getting uniqueness violates constraints error for game with gameID ...**. How can I create a new game vertex with different gameId as a property for both winners and participants.
If I try the query without adding game vertex then, **multiple wonGift edges are creating for the participants**

This is the query:

```
g.withSideEffect('curTime', 1599469059825)
.V().hasLabel('Competition').has('competitionId', 'competition-OY-KzEt_H')
.has('active', true).as('c')
.project('participantCount', 'winner').
by(select('c').inE('participatedIn').has('batch', 1).has('isEligible', true).count()).
by(select('c').inE('participatedIn').has('batch', 1).has('isEligible', true).as('pe')
    .choose(
        has('picked', true), outV().valueMap().fold(), 
        
        sample(2).property('earlybirdPicked', true).outV().as('winner')
        .sideEffect(select('pe').hasNot('picked').property('picked', false))
        .sideEffect(
            choose(
                select('c').has('competitionType', 'online'), 

                select('winner')
                .addE('wonGift').property('typeOfGift', 'points')
                .property('pointsScored', 200)
                .property('on', 1599469059825).to('c')
                .select('winner')
                .addV('Game')
                .property('gameId', `game-${Math.random()}`)
                .property('pointsScored', 200)
                .addE('participates')
                .to('winner')
                .select('c')
                .inE('participatedIn')
                .has('batch', 1)
                .has('isEligible', true)
                .has('picked', false)
                .outV().as('participant')
                .addE('wonGift').property('typeOfGift', 'points')
                .property('pointsScored', 100)
                .property('on', 1599469059825).to('c')
                .select('participant')
                .addV('Game')
                .property('gameId', `game-${Math.random()}`)
                .property('pointsScored', 100)
                .addE('participates')
                .to('participant')
            )
        ).select('winner').valueMap().fold()
    )
)
```

Please find the script to add default data below:

```
g.addV('Person').as('1').
property(single, 'callingName', 'Sharath').
  property(single, 'personId', 'zefasdafas').
  addV('Person').as('2').
  property(single, 'callingName', 'Raj').
  property(single, 'personId', 'sVzqUTNVkar').
  addV('Person').as('3').
  property(single, 'callingName', 'Hima').
  property(single, 'personId', 'ajlsdfj').
  addV('Competition').as('4').
  property(single, 'competitionId', 'ag-competition-sVzVkar').
  property(single, 'active', true).
  property(single, 'competitionType', 'online').
  addV('Person').as('5').
  property(single, 'callingName', 'Ram').
  property(single, 'personID', 'asdfasewr').
  addV('Person').as('6').
  property(single, 'callingName', 'shiva').
  property(single, 'personID', '98iejalsd').
  addV('Person').as('7').
  property(single, 'callingName', 'Andhrew').
  property(single, 'personID', 'aui;lkj').
  addV('Person').as('8').
  property(single, 'callingName', 'Naveen').
  property(single, 'personID', 'naedloli').
  addV('Person').as('9').
  property(single, 'callingName', 'Euler').
  property(single, 'personID', 'aek,kndal').
  addV('Person').as('10').
  property(single, 'callingName', 'Rahul').
  property(single, 'personID', 'rahoil;lj').
  addV('Person').as('11').
  property(single, 'callingName', 'Vijay').
  property(single, 'personID', 'vijiouik').
  addV('Person').as('12').
  property(single, 'callingName', 'Ravali').
  property(single, 'personID', 'raikjlka').
  addV('Person').as('13').
  property(single, 'callingName', 'Sirisha').
  property(single, 'personID', 'siriosjdkl').
  addE('participatedIn').from('2').to('4').
  property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1).addE('participatedIn').
  from('1').to('4').property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1).addE('participatedIn').
  from('3').to('4').property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1).addE('participatedIn').
  from('5').to('4').property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1).addE('participatedIn').
  from('6').to('4').property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1).addE('participatedIn').
  from('7').to('4').property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1).addE('participatedIn').
  from('8').to('4').property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1).addE('participatedIn').
  from('9').to('4').property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1).addE('participatedIn').
  from('10').to('4').property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1).addE('participatedIn').
  from('11').to('4').property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1).addE('participatedIn').
  from('12').to('4').property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1).addE('participatedIn').
  from('13').to('4').property('picked', false).
  property('isEligible', true).
  property('batch', 1)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide a Graph example? you can create one in gremlify.com or add a gremlin script that generates some data

Comment: @noam621 Added gremlin script to add default data

Answer (score 1):

I can see what is wrong, but I don't know how you want to fix it. This line:

```
sample(2).property('earlybirdPicked', true).outV().as('winner')
```

chooses two edges at random and then for each edge you `choose('c').inE('participatedIn')` which of course means you iterate those "participatedIn" edges twice and then doing `addE()` twice. If you change to `sample(3)` you should get participants with 100 points created even more times.

One way to fix it would be to just update the "200 point winners" in that `sideEffect()` and then deal with the "100 point winners" afterward.

```
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('curTime', 1599469059825).
......1>   V().hasLabel('Competition').
......2>   has('competitionId', 'ag-competition-sVzVkar').
......3>   has('active', true).as('c').
......4>   project('participantCount', 'winner').
......5>     by(inE('participatedIn').has('batch', 1).
......6>        has('isEligible', true).count()).
......7>     by(inE('participatedIn').has('batch', 1).
......8>        has('isEligible', true).
......9>        choose(has('picked', true),
.....10>               outV(),
.....11>               sideEffect(hasNot('picked').property('picked', false)).
.....12>               sample(2).property('earlybirdPicked', true).outV().
.....13>               sideEffect(choose(select('c').has('competitionType', 'online'),
.....14>                                 addE('wonGift').
.....15>                                   property('typeOfGift', 'points').
.....16>                                   property('pointsScored', 200).
.....17>                                   property('on', 1599469059825).to('c')))).
.....18>        valueMap().fold()).
.....19>   sideEffect(select('c').
.....20>              inE('participatedIn').has('batch', 1).has('isEligible', true).has('picked', false).
.....21>              outV().as('participant').
.....22>              addE('wonGift').
.....23>                property('typeOfGift', 'points').
.....24>                property('pointsScored', 100).
.....25>                property('on', 1599469059825).to('c'))
==>[participantCount:12,winner:[[callingName:[Sirisha],personID:[siriosjdkl]],[callingName:[Ravali],personID:[raikjlka]]]]
gremlin> g.E().hasLabel('wonGift').elementMap()
==>[id:64,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:22,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:65,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:25,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:52,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:37,label:Person],pointsScored:200,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:53,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:34,label:Person],pointsScored:200,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:54,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:28,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:55,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:31,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:56,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:34,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:57,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:37,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:58,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:3,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:59,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:0,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:60,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:6,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:61,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:13,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:62,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:16,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
==>[id:63,label:wonGift,IN:[id:9,label:Competition],OUT:[id:19,label:Person],pointsScored:100,typeOfGift:points,on:1599469059825]
```

I think that gives you the correct number of edges. I also got rid of a bunch of step labels and backtracking and I think that made the traversal a bit easier to read. There is room for more optimization I think as this approach has you traverse "participatedIn" edges three times total. I imagine this could be restructured to do that once, but that might come at a sacrifice to readability. You also have some fairly specific business logic here that I was trying not to mess up so I didn't want to tinker with the overall query structure too much.

Comment: In the last sideEffect you are not checking whether the competition is online or not and also whether the winners are already generated. Only if the winners are not generated and competition is online, then only wonGift edge should be added. And also I want to add a new game vertex to both the winners and participants with different gameId (which should be generated randomly based on timestamp. ex: competition-153235235234).
I have updated the exact requirement and the query. Please go through it once